# Can't boot ubuntu, deleted 86_64x gnu accidently

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, python, opencv

Hi please help by mistake I deleted all of x86_64 linux folder and now the boot got stuck. Please help thank you

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you have done, eg. a quick scan of my own system finds a number of directories named "x86_64" in the system, and most would have **no** impact on booting at all, impacting only the programs they're involved with. For specific help, you should be specific as to what you did.

Comment: Hi I accidentally deleted the x86_64 folder from my ubuntu I by mistake put *Run as administrator* in /usr/ directly and then went to *include* so now I am in */usr/include* and then deleted the x84_64-gnu folder like an idiot

Comment: So is there a way to clean and fix my ubuntu or should I reinstall the OS, please help, thank you

Comment: If you can re-install the OS, you can perform the answer already provided by @Matigo as it's using that *live* system (eg. installation media) that performs that function.  The ISO doesn't need to be on thumb-drive, it can be cd/dvd/hdd/ssd or even a ISO file on *file-system*, it can be anything your system can boot from.  No you don't need to re-install the OS.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without that os install, cuz I don't have pen drive and I don't have that file downloaded here please help

Comment: As I said in the first comment, I don't know what you have removed.  I did a search for directories titled "x86_64" on my current system, and got 15 directories with that exact name. As I stated in my first comment, most of those directories will have no impact on booting; so I asked for clarification on what command, or directory you actually deleted as currently your situation is unclear.

Comment: I deleted something called x86_64-gnu-linux

Comment: Where x86_64 found 15 results on my Ubuntu system, a search for `x86_64-gnu-linux` (ie. `find / -name x86_64-gnu-linux 2>/dev/null`) finds **no** results on my system.  It's difficult for us to provide specific help, when we don't know exactly what you did; restoration of your backups maybe easiest.  (my guess is you removed from `/boot`; but that's just guess; we have no details on how far you get in the boot process, any error messages you see, if you tried booting to runlevel 1, recovery etc)

Comment: I don't know which file exactly that was a guess I made

Comment: I would boot *live* media and have a look at your `history` (ie. command history) to see what exactly you did, if you didn't use commands look at the *file-system* and explore.  If you don't have *live* media; my own systems are usually dual-boot, so I'd just use the other system to explore from there (you won't have that option if you don't dual boot, or have compatible system setup for that before-hand). In future I'd keep *live* media handy; it's a useful tool to solve mistakes (not just your own, but other peoples; can't you borrow a *live* system from a technical friend? or write one?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Boot Repair" for this. Grab the Live USB/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu with and boot into a live session. Make sure you have an Internet connection when doing so. Once you're in the GUI, open terminal. You will need to install some packages:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once this is all said and done, run:

```
boot-repair
```

Click "Recommended Repair" and follow the wizard.

[image: Boot Repair]

This should give you a bootable machine again.

Comment: How to boot into terminal

Comment: Boot into the live session, *then* open a Terminal. You can do that by searching for the Terminal application, or by pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T] 

Comment: First I am stuck at the boot screen itself, I can't even login

Comment: You are unable to boot from the Live USB device? If so, that's a different problem ...

Comment: @Matigo suggested a *live* session, that is a thumb-drive which thus bypasses the issue of your *installed system failing to boot*.  It's using Ubuntu installation media and just using the "*Try Ubuntu*" section.  It doesn't need to be the same version you have installed, though ideally it should be of same vintage or newer.

Comment: Hi I don't have usb for now